# How to charge and order for specific products using stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments, payment, stripe-connect

Suppose I have a product `prod_1`. What are the steps to create an order for `prod_1` and charge it?

I'm thinking the order would be

```
1 create order
2 get source token
3 pay order
```

Where do I tell it how much to charge? I need to create a `charge` but not sure I can pass that to the order.

How to I assign this order to a product?

note: I don't want to get a customer involved in this transaction. That's the reason I'm getting a 'source token'

Any ideas?

Comment: Are these physical products?  Do you have a set quantity that you can sell (like t-shirts or stickers or something)?  If not, you probably don't want to use products, but rather Invoice Items ( https://stripe.com/docs/api#invoiceitem_object ) and Invoices ( https://stripe.com/docs/api#invoice_object ).

Comment: They are not physical items. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stripe has no concept of "products" - all it's concerned with is a `Charge`, which sets the amount of money you want to extract from your visitor's wallets.

And the amount charged is set on the `Charge` entity. In PHP, like so:

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    'amount'   => $amountYouWantToChargeInIntegralUsdCents,
    'currency' => 'usd'
));
```

In the Stripe.com web-application there is a heading "Relay" with the options "Products" and "Orders", however this refers to "[Stripe Relay](https://stripe.com/relay)" which is meant [for creating mini-marketplaces within smartphone apps](https://stripe.com/blog/relay), it is irrelevant to normal Stripe payments.

Comment: There is definitely a `products` section in there as well as `orders`.. and they are referenced in the api

Comment: @Patrioticcow That's for "Stripe Relay" which is separate from Stripe-proper.

Comment: I see. I guess I can use them as a reference only. Thank you